# Where can i get any Screencasts for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

Where can I get any Screencasts, Webcasts, Training Video's, Cbt's ect for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Main Page with a host of tutorials etc:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html

Few Videos:
http://video.google.com.au/videoplay?docid=5745755015991749390#
Great Google Search turns up a bunch of misc Postgres Vids:
http://video.google.com.au/videosearch?q=Postgres+SQL&emb=0#
http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/postgresql

Finding ScreenCasts
http://video.google.com/videosearch?rlz=1C1GPMD_enUS328US331&sourceid=chrome&q=postgres+screencast&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=59gyS9PeIs7ZnAfzq6ntCA&sa=X&oi=video_result_group&ct=title&resnum=4&ved=0CBUQqwQwAw#

Answer (score 1):

[peepcode screencast](http://peepcode.com/products/postgresql)